# Sqllite query for getting last increased value from my database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am inserting data into a table in Sqllite DataBase which are ever increasing , if it decreased at some time, it uses the last increased value as base. See the following table where fields are Application, time and Data Captured at that time.

```
>1. YouTube     04:10PM     200KB 
>2. YouTube     04:20PM     400KB
>3. YouTube     05:10PM     100KB 
>4. YouTube     06:10PM     200KB
>5. YouTube     07:10PM     600KB 
>6. YouTube     08:10PM     500KB
>7. YouTube     08:40PM     700KB
>8. YouTube     08:40PM     100KB
>9. YouTube     09:10PM     200KB 
>10. YouTube        10:10PM     600KB
```

As data decreased in 3 , from 3 to 6(i.e till data are increasing), i need to access 2. Again in 6, Value is decrased. So from 6 to 7, i need to access last increased value in 5. Again in 8, the Value is decreased. So from 8 to 10, i will access last increased value in 7.

So basically I will use the last increased value. I can't find a proper sql query which will get me the last increased value from my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly MAX(Data Captured) should do the trick

Comment: i think,i need MAX(Data Captured) of most recent time. For most recent time, what should i do.

Comment: If you want the highest value within a given time frame use:
select MAX(kb) from Table where date beteeen 'datefrom' and 'dateto'.

Comment: Do you need to have the maximum value from when the previous value is lower/higher than the current?

Comment: Yes,I need to have the maximum value from now where the previous value is higher than the current?